# ToWekaUtils-- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I have run  a code containing some methods. every thing should be OK and the program is running well until it reach the following method, it stopped and give me an error. The method as follows

```
 public void ClassifierDT() {
        setClassifier(new WekaClassifier(new REPTree()));
        System.out.println("Myclassifier: new  DT - REPTree()");
    }
```

And the error that I got as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lweka/core/FastVector;)V
    at net.sf.javaml.tools.weka.ToWekaUtils.<init>(ToWekaUtils.java:48)
    at net.sf.javaml.tools.weka.ToWekaUtils.<init>(ToWekaUtils.java:48)
    at net.sf.javaml.tools.weka.WekaClassifier.buildClassifier(WekaClassifier.java:27)
```

Does the error related to weka jar file? it may need a newest version or what ?

could someone help? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have just one jar file for the Weka lib in your classpath? How do you run your application?

Comment: Yes I have only one weka jar file.